# Is there a way I can access a .json file only from node js script, and prevent the direct access using URL?

Tags: android, node.js, security, nginx, server

I'm using a nginx server, I am creating an android app, it uses a json file on server for specific functionality, Now this json file if I access from its URL, it opens on the browser, I want it to be accessed only from my app as it contains some important information, I'm aware of jwt tokens, I thought of using it with node js to get the contents of the file, still the file will be accessible with its URL, any way I can prevent it?

Another tip I wanted is, Is it good to access the json file from node js, or direct access of json file is more efficient, considering the server load

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the json file outside of the nginx root directory, that way nobody can access it by url alone.

For example, if this is your machine's directory.

```
my-project/
  src/
    index.js
  public/ # nginx root dir  
    file.json # move this outside of public/
  private/
    file.json # you can move it here
```

After that, you can use JWT's to protect the route that'll serve the json file. Here's an example from express docs. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

```
app.use(jwtMiddleware) // google for "express jwt middleware"

app.get('/file/:name', function (req, res, next) {

  var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/path/to/jsonfile',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
  };

  var fileName = req.params.name;
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
    }
  });

});
```

> Another tip I wanted is, Is it good to access the json file from node js, or direct access of json file is more efficient, considering the server load

If your JSON file was public, then it would make sense to have nginx serve it. However, your json file requires authentication, and that logic is easier to implement in node, rather than nginx.

Comment: Thank you @EricGuan